# Pulsating brakes and vibrating car after pad replacement (that later went away), should I continue driving?

Tags: brakes, heat, cadillac, brake-pad

I have changed brakes at local auto garage. On first drive around the town and local road brakes heated up to almost red smoke was coming and I was worried that tires will get on fire, you could hear the clicking sound that metal makes. I know it's normal for brakes to heat up on few first drives.

Today I did second major drive (~140 miles). At first I was driving through the city and brakes heated up to the point where smoke was coming as I could smell it. Then I got to motorway at around 70 mph my Cadillac CTS suddenly started vibrating so I bumped the up speed and it went away. After driving for 30 minutes or so I dropped speed back to 70, and vibrations were gone. Upon arrival I checked the brakes by spitting and they were hot but not too much just slight hissing.

**Is it safe to drive (or should I go moan to auto garage about this)?**

Comment: I suggest you go moan. This is not normal